# django table form ad a 3rd column for errors

Tags: django, forms, widget, html-table

I am trying to get my possible error messages in a 3rd column behind the input fields. but except for customizing my whole html in my template I have no idea how to do this. An with my eyes on the widgets and ModelForm class I guess there should be something for it.

My form:

```
class ProvinceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to create or edit Provinces."""

    name = forms.CharField()
    choice_set = Country.objects.all()
    country= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=choice_set, empty_label="Choose its country")
    flavor = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'width': 300, 'height': 200}))

    class Meta:
        model = Province
```

And then my template:

```
<form action="{% url 'create_province' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ province_form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="float: right;"><input type="submit" value="add province" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What would be the logical way to add that 3rd column instead of stripping the whole `{{ province_form.as_table }}` apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render each field separately as:

```
<table>
    {% for field in province_form %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{field.label}}</td> <td> {{field}} </td> <td> {{field.errors}} </td>
    </tr> 
    {%endfor%}
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="float: right;"><input type="submit" value="add province" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Note: you may want to change rendering of errors appropriately by looping over `{{field.errors}}`.